# Cannot render from CLI: wm_main_playanim_intern: no filepath argument given

Tags: rendering, error, command-line

When I try to render from CLI using something like:

```
blender '/home/lxif/VFX/OZELOT/vfx clip/VFX/scenes/TREES _ FLOOR/FLOOR_2.blend' -a
```

irrespective of what file I try to render, I get the following errors:

```
AL lib: (EE) GetLoadedHrtf: Invalid header in /usr/share/openal/hrtf/default-44100.mhr: "MinPHR02"
AL lib: (EE) GetLoadedHrtf: Failed to load /usr/share/openal/hrtf/default-44100.mhr
AL lib: (EE) GetLoadedHrtf: Invalid header in /usr/share/openal/hrtf/default-48000.mhr: "MinPHR02"
AL lib: (EE) GetLoadedHrtf: Failed to load /usr/share/openal/hrtf/default-48000.mhr
wm_main_playanim_intern: no filepath argument given
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

If I use sudo, I only get:

```
wm_main_playanim_intern: no filepath argument given
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

What can I do to alleviate this? I want to be able to render multiple files overnight.

xx

Comment: Ok, so it works when I add -b; I wanted to try with GUI at first to be sure. Weird that it doesn't work without -b, but no worries here anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
blender -b '/home/lxif/VFX/OZELOT/vfx clip/VFX/scenes/TREES _ FLOOR/FLOOR_2.blend' -a
```

You missed the **`-b`** option, that tells blender to *batch render*.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html